# Learning Somewhat Advanced Topics in General Topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning

I think I have background in general topology on undergraduate (Munkres) level and also some background in functional analysis. Without Filters and Nets . However, there are still topics, which I wish to learn, because I keep hearing about them from other people, but don't have much experience with using them. Recently I decided to learn all this topics and decided to work them out from Engelking's book that seems to be the most complete book on the subject. At this moment I have climbed up to Stone-Cech compactification and Wallman extension. Which are useful and interesting concepts themselves, however I really wanted a different exposition (more modern, filter and category based). Moreover Engelking's exposition is overbloated and very terse.  So I feel that working through his book, despite it being a great reference book, really slows me down.

Now I found this [document](https://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/classes/9293/131/ultra.pdf) by Dror Bar-Natan. It is very compact and contains only statements of main results, which I can try to prove myself. This format now seems optimal for my goal.But the problem is finding similar references for other topics. Here is a list of topics I wish to learn:

1. Stone-Cech compactification as a functor (in filter setting)
2. General Baire Spaces and Baire category
3. Metric spaces with geodesics and Hopf-Rinow theorem (*),(!)
4. Nagata-Smirnov Metrization Theorem
5. Uniform spaces
6. Baire category for metric or uniform spaces
7. Basic topics in connectedness(*),(!)
8. Basic topological dimension (*)
9. General topological algebra

(*) - means that I have idea on what reference to use
(!) - means that I should know this material but I still wont to brush it up

I would very grateful if you can share your experience about learning these topics and, if you know any, references to which are similar in spirit with the document above. It would be very valuable for me, if it uses category or sheaf theory, or applications to measure theory, functional analysis or metric or differential geometry.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Engelking's general topology book is still introductory while being considerably more advanced than Munkres's and it covers most of the stuff you're interested in

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti The only books in general topology, which can't be called introductory, from what I have seen so far, is Topics in General Topology by Morita and Nagata. But this is a collection of disconnected topics, not a textbook.

Comment: The "Encyclopia of General Topology" has many short surveys, with results and references. This might be useful as a starting point.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks a lot. I will definitely check it out.

Comment: For certain topics, possibly [**General Topology**](https://www.worldcat.org/title/general-topology/oclc/4146011) ([table of contents](http://www.gbv.de/dms/hbz/toc/ht000078331.pdf)) by Ákos Császár (1978). Reviews I know of: [**Mathematical Gazette**](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3618060) and [unknown journal](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/4615307B8E89B659AFF018CA036A3AB3/S0013091500027905a.pdf/csaszar_general_topology_adam_hilger_1978_488_pp_2050.pdf) and **Publicationes Mathematicae Debrecen** 26 #3-4 (November 1979), pp. 308-309 (not on internet).

Comment: I got a very nice hardback copy of Császár's 1978 book about a year ago, and this book is definitely very individualistic --- it is rather advanced in some topics, like uniform and proximity spaces, while still being almost excessively complete in providing every minor mathematical detail. For a very nice and easy to read introductory treatment of compactifications, see [**Hausdorff Compactifications**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824765591) by Richard E. Chandler (FYI, he was on my Ph.D. committee). **(continued)**

Comment: Incidentally, 4.8, 4.10, 4.12, 4.13, 4.15 on pp. 34-36 of Chandler's book are false if ${\omega}_{\alpha}$ has countably infinite cofinality. These results were taken from [Gillman/Jerison](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486816885) in which G/J's hypothesis that $\alpha \geq 1$ is a nonlimit ordinal was inadvertently overlooked. This aside, Chandler is an expert on the topic, and thus the book is quite authoritatively written (also very well written), and yet it is still extremely accessible to someone first learning the subject.

Comment: [**Set-Theoretic Topology**](https://www.worldcat.org/title/set-theoretic-topology-with-emphasis-on-problems-from-the-theory-of-coverings-zero-dimensionality-and-cardinal-invariants/oclc/2911241) by Gregory L. Naber (1977) is a little-known book that gives a transition treatment between Engelking's book and the set-theoretic topology literature ([Bull. AMS review](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183540523)). For more category-theoretic treatments, perhaps try googling with [Horst] "Herrlich".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for all your recommendations.