# Distinct topological compactifications

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, compactification

I'm looking for distinct topological compactifications (I know about the Stone-Cech compactification and the Alexandroff compactification). I would also like some examples of each (e.g. the Alexandroff compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ is $S^1$).

Comment: I recommend the book see [**Hausdorff Compactifications**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824765591) by Richard E. Chandler. A few weeks ago [I wrote some comments about Chandler's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638309/learning-somewhat-advanced-topics-in-general-topology#comment7477726_3638309) that might be of interest.

Comment: A space like $\omega_1$ has a *unique* Hausdorff compactification... So there need not be distinct ones.

Comment: But there are, each with different properties...

Comment: I like the Freudenthal/[end compactification](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/end+compactification). If you're asking for a list, I would start with [the list of pages on nLab that have "compactification" in the name](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/search?query=compactification), which has a lot already.